# HttpServletResponse produces corrupted UTF-8 data

Tags: jakarta-ee, utf-8, jersey

I'm making RESTful service using Jersey, which produce UTF-8 encoded replies.
Here is a code snippet:

```
public static class Data {

    private String value;

    public Data(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response method() {

    Data response = new Data("€");
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                   .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
                   .entity(response)
                   .build();
}
```

It's supposed to produce the following reply:

```
{"value":"€"}
```

or as byte array:

```
[123, 34, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 34, 58, 34, -30, -126, -84, 34, 125]
```

Note, that Euro sign is encoded as three bytes -30, -126, -84 or [0xe2 0x82 0xac](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm).

However, it produces the following response

```
{"value":"â¬"}
```

or as byte array:

```
[123, 34, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 34, 58, 34, -61, -94, -62, -126, -62, -84, 34, 125]
```

Note, that Euro sign is encoded as six bytes now -61, -94, -62, -126, -62, -84 or 0xc3 0xa2 0xc2 0x82 0xc2 0xac.

I've found a conversion sequence, which results in such corruption, at some point UTF-8 encoded data is treated as Latin1 encoded data.

```
Data data = new Data("€");
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper mapper
    = new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper();
try {
    String strData = mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
    System.out.println(strData);
    byte[] rawData = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(data);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rawData));

    String asLatin1 = new String(rawData, "ISO-8859-1");
    byte[] brokenUtf8 = asLatin1.getBytes("UTF-8");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(brokenUtf8));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Fail " + e.getMessage());
}
```

The service runs on two machines one with apache-tomcat-7.0.30 and another in apache-tomcat-7.0.23. The former produces correct UTF-8 response, while the latter has corrupted UTF-8. I'm unable to find out what causes difference in behavior and what could resolve the problem.

Comment: It looks like the receiver is decoding it as latin1, that's a configuration issue or issue in code using default encoding

Comment: @Esailija: The receiver is curl command line utility or browser, both are using UTF-8. I'm sure it's not receiver problem.

Comment: What I understood from your post is you have one server that posts legit UTF-8 to another server, and the another server interprets it and dumps the result..

Comment: @Esailija: I have two servers running the same service and there is the same receiver - curl or browser. And corruption sequence involves UTF-16: UTF-8 -> ISO-8859-1 -> UTF-16 -> UTF-8. In practice only Java uses UTF-16, so corruption happens on Java side.

Comment: If you have Server1 -> Server2 -> Client there are 2 receivers. What I meant to say that Server1 sends UTF-8 to Server2, Server2 interprets it in Latin1, and sends UTF-8 to Client, explaining the 6 bytes seen in Client

Comment: @Esailija: Sorry, I have two servers running the same service and there is the same receiver - curl or browser.

Comment: Please right click the file containing `"€"` in eclipse project explorer, click Properties, and in the Resource tab of Properties for the file, see what the Text file encoding is.

Comment: It's UTF-8 http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm - 0xE2 0x82 0xAC is exactly [-30, -126, -84] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had a very sad reason and it was very hard to find.
Ant's javac task had explicit encoding set:

```
<javac destdir="${classes}" includeantruntime="false" source="1.6" target="1.6" debug="true" encoding="ISO-8859-1" classpathref="main.classpath">
```

It was working under one Tomcat because it was built with Eclipse and another deployment was built with Ant, corrupting all Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

If it works in 7.0.30 and not in 7.0.23 perhaps it's a bug that was found and fixed?  Have you checked out the [Tomcat changelog](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html) to see if there is anything in there?

Comment: Probability of Apache Tomcat 7.0.23 having a bug, so it was not able to produce UTF-8 response and I'm the first person to notice that is too low to be taken seriously.